# how to solve a simplex with n variables

Tags: linear-programming, economics, simplex

I don't know how to resolve a simplex with **$n$ variables**

I have this primal problem
\begin{cases}
\text{min}& z=-x_1 - x_2  -\cdots - x_n\\
&a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +\cdots   + a_nx_n \le 1\\
&x_1,\dots, x_n \ge 0\\
&a_1,\dots, a_n \gt 0
\end{cases}

I found that the dual problem is

\begin{cases}
\text{max}& w=y_1 + y_2  +\cdots + y_n\\
&a_1y_1  \ge -1\\
&a_2y_1  \ge -1\\
&\vdots\\
&a_ny_1  \ge -1\\
&y_1,\dots, y_n \ge 0\\
&a_1,\dots,a_n \gt 0
\end{cases}

Do I need to use simplex method or Complementary Slackness Theorem to solve this problem ? 
My first guess what to write :

$(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)y_1 \ge -n$

then I have $y_1 \ge \dfrac{-1}{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)}$

but it doesn't solve the problem.

If I add the slack variable I think we could see a solution but the obvious solution is that $y_1 = 0$ ...

If someone can explain me how to find the solution I would be grateful

Comment: I think the dual that you've found is *incorrect*.  The objective function of the dual should be $w = z_1$, without $y_2,\dots,y_n$.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

Actually, the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Programming (which asserts that for every feasible (optimal) solution, there exists a *basic* feasible (optimal) solution) will give you the answer.  Using the Strong Duality Theorem and working on the dual problem will give you similar procedures and the *same* answer.  If the primal problem is correct, then a basic solution will be $x_i = \dfrac1{a_i}$, which gives the objective function value $-\dfrac1{a_i}$, so the optimal value for this minimization problem will be $\min\left\{-\dfrac1{a_i}:1\le i\le n\right\}$.

### Method 2

If you insist on finding the dual problem, then it should be

$\max w = y_1$ subject to
\begin{align}
a_1 y_1 &\le -1 \\
a_2 y_1 &\le -1 \\
&\vdots \\
a_n y_1 &\le -1 \\
y_1&\le 0
\end{align}

That is to $\max w = -y_1$ subject to
\begin{align}
a_1 y_1 &\ge 1 \\
a_2 y_1 &\ge 1 \\
&\vdots \\
a_n y_1 &\ge 1 \\
y_1&\ge 0
\end{align}
Then $-y_i \le -\dfrac1{a_i} \;\forall 1 \le i \le n \iff -y_i \le \min \left\{-\dfrac1{a_i}:1\le i\le n\right\}$, so the result is still the same.

### Comparison of the two methods

Of course using the first method is faster: you just substitute the numbers to get a basic solution.  Using the second method, one needs to write down the dual.  Then you need to handle those "forall" stuff before getting the answer.